# some rules are misbehaving in 1 of the 2 drools server

Tags: java, drools, rules, rule-engine, drools-flow

I do not know, what is the exact problem, so explaining the scenario here:

I have 2 drools server in my production setup, and with the campaign changes, deployment of new rules happen so frequently, almost 5-7 times a day,and it happens dynamically, on the running servers through watch-scanners.

We observed a weird issue here, sometimes, in 1 out of 2 servers, some rules are not working but it is working on the other server, but when I restart the same server, it starts working.

I have put the logs, and saw, jars are scanned successfully everytime, but still drools is not able to absorb rule jar completely in some cases.

**setup Details:**
I have 2 servers, in which drools servers are running, and 1 more server, where I use to build the rules through kie-workbench, rules jar are transferred to these 2 servers, through jenkins job, it copies the jar from the kie workbench server to other 2 servers, and I have placed watch-scanners, which will get the event, when new jar will be uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Drools rule engine uses kie-container, in which it deploys all the rules and analyse them, so when you deploy the rule on the existing container, may be it is not able to replace the new tree with existing one completely, thats why the error was occuring, so I made a change, where I will create a new kie container every time, when I will deploy the new rule set.